subsetting withinin ggplot2 command
Sorry if there´s already a thread on this, but I could´t find ther solution for my problem with existing posts!
I try to create a barplot subsetting a large dataframe in the gplot2 code. This is a simplified example of how my df looks like:



location
year
measurement
value
treatment




1
22
parameter1
3
A


2
23
parameter2
2
B


2
24
parameter1
4
A


1
22
parameter3
2
C



What I try to get are basicly distinct barplots for location 1 and 2, compairing the values from different measurements in dependence of treatment over time. Values should be shown on the y-axis, year on the x-axis and the treatment displayed by the filling. I´d like to understand how to put all this into my ggplot-code instaed of creating 1000 subsets.
That´s the code I came up with:
  plot_location1<-
  ggplot(df[df$location=="1",]+
  aes(fill=treatment, y=total[total$measurement=="parameter1",] x=year) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity"))

I´ve been playing around with this structure since a bit and keep receiving different error messages; with the upper code it says list of length 3 not meaningful. I´m happy to learn how to effectively subset within the ggplot command, as I guess that´s what I´m doing wrong :P
Many thanks in advance!

Like this?
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  location = c(1, 2, 2, 1),
  year = c(22, 23, 24, 22),
  measurement = c("parameter1", "parameter2", "parameter1", "parameter3"),
  value = c(3, 2, 4, 2),
  treatment = c("A", "B", "A", "C")
)

ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(year), y = value, fill = treatment)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
  facet_wrap(~ location) +
  labs(x = "Year", y = "Value", fill = "Treatment") +
  theme_minimal()



Thanks, that´solves already half of the problem :)
Now I just had to specify to choose only the values for one parameter by time: 'ggplot(df[df$measurement=="parameter1",],...' That gives me exactly what I need.
